# Google Sheets script: fastest way to search for a string (position not needed)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to find the quickest way to find a string in a sheet and I don't need to know the location of the string, I just need to know if it's already there.

I have tried this:

```
 var raw = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("raw");
 var raw_content = raw.getDataRange();    
 var textFinder = raw_content.createTextFinder(unique_id);
 var occurrences = textFinder.findAll().map(x => x.getA1Notation());
```

This takes around 140ms

And also this:

```
function StrSearch(searchString) 
{
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("raw");
var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

for(var i=0, iLen=values.length; i<iLen; i++) 
  {
    if(values[i][0] == searchString) 
      {
        return values[i][1];
      }
  }
}
```

I have around 30 labels to check for 100 different dates which means checking 3000 times if the values are already there. Most of the time, it hits the timeout limit in Google Sheets.

I was wondering if there would be a quicker way of doing this as I'm interested to know where the string is, I just need to know it's there. The string is available in one specific column which means that I don't even need to search for the whole sheet.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: I cannot image your situation from `I have around 30 labels to check for 100 different dates which means checking 3000 times if the values are already there.` and `The string is available in one specific column which means that I don't even need to search for the whole sheet.`. I apologize for my poor English skill. Can you provide the sample situation as an image? By the way, how do you want to execute the script? It's as the custom function?

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks. I have basically one sheet with 30 lines, each line contains a regular expression corresponding to the type of report I want to get out of the GA API. I need to retrieve the data for each of those lines for the past 100 days. Ex: ga:eventAction==ORA_link. So I query the API with this filter and one date. I store the results in another sheet for analysis but I need to make sure I don't store twice the same data.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you don't need to know the location of the string, just whether it's in the sheet? If that's the case, why do you do `.map(x => x.getA1Notation());`? Also, no need to use `getDataRange`, since class `Sheet` has the method `createTextFinder` too.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot still image about your situation from your replying. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand about your situation, I would like to think of the solution. I deeply apologize I cannot resolve your issue soon.

Answer (score 1):

The performance issue may be because you are calling the `StrSearch()` function many times, and it reads the data from the spreadsheet every time separately. You can make it considerably faster by reading the data just once.

Try this:

```
/**
* Gets text strings from a range and returns the ones that appear in a sheet.
*
* Usage in Apps Script:
*   const matches = findMatchesInSheet('SearchKeys!A2:A', 'RawDataSheet');
*
* Usage in a spreadsheet formula:
*   =findMatchesInSheet("SearchKeys!A2:A", "RawDataSheet")
*
* @param {String} searchKeyRangeA1 A1 notation of the range where search keys are.
* @param {String} sheetName The name of the sheet to search.
* @return {String[]} The search keys that were found in the sheet.
* @customfunction
*/
function findMatchesInSheet(searchKeyRangeA1, sheetName) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const searchFor = ss.getRange(searchKeyRangeA1).getDisplayValues()
    .flat().filter(String);
  const searchIn = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName).getDataRange().getDisplayValues()
    .flat().join('µ');
  return searchFor
    .filter(searchString => searchIn.indexOf(searchString) !== -1);
}
```

Comment: This finds partial matches as well as full matches. To find full matches only, use `const searchIn = 'µ' + ss...join('µ') + 'µ';` and `=> searchIn.indexOf('µ' + searchString + 'µ') !== -1`.

Answer (score 1):

all your answers helped me dig further into this problem and I ended up with a different solution.

Initial way of working

- read all the filters to collect in sheet "RAW"
- combine the filter with a date to create a unique label
- check if this unique label is already in my final sheet
- if yes, do nothing, if no get the data from GA and write it

I changed into the following

- read all the filters to collect in sheet "RAW"
- make one query per filter for 100 days instead of day by day
- dump the result in my final sheet
- remove duplicates at the end

The whole process now takes around 100 seconds (calls to API included).

I use the following function for removing duplicates

```
function removeDuplicates() {
Logger.log('start duplicates '+Date.now());
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("raw");
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var newData = [];
for (var i in data) {
  var row = data[i];
  var duplicate = false;
  for (var j in newData) {
    if (row.join() == newData[j].join()) {
      duplicate = true;
    }
  }
  if (!duplicate) {
    newData.push(row);
  }
}
sheet.clearContents();
sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
 Logger.log('end duplicates '+Date.now());
```

}

This function takes up to 50% of the total time but it still reasonable.

Thanks